# Перехват Ping у клиента WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket

Есть вебсокет клиент на Java (javax). Сервер периодически отправляет ping запросы, дабы проверить активность соединения. Нужно ли обрабатывать Pong со стороны клиента? Если нет, то как можно отловить пинг, чтобы прологировать?

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket: [PING / PONG](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#ping-pong)

В протокол встроена проверка связи при помощи управляющих фреймов типа PING и PONG.

Тот, кто хочет проверить соединение, отправляет фрейм PING с произвольным телом. Его получатель должен в разумное время ответить фреймом PONG с тем же телом.

Этот функционал встроен в браузерную реализацию, так что браузер ответит на PING сервера, но управлять им из JavaScript нельзя.

Comment: Здесь в роли клиента выступает Java приложение (javax). Есть ли возможность прологировать пинг с сервера, т.е. переопределить Pong?